# OrientDB SQL query to Native Fluent API call

Tags: java, orientdb

How can I represent the OrientDB SQL query

```
traverse out(vertex_item) from #12:3 while $depth <= 4
```

in a native Java query? I.e. I'm looking for a query utilizing the Native Fluent API, with its `OTraverse` objects.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately the OTraverse class hasn't been updated with last changes introduced in OrientDB 1.4. So you've to express the entire field name:

```
for (OIdentifiable id : new OTraverse().field("out_vertex_item")target(new ORecordId("#12:3")
                         .predicate(new OCommandPredicate() {
  public Object evaluate(ORecord<?> iRecord, ODocument iCurrentResult, OCommandContext iContext) {
    return ((Integer) iContext.getVariable("depth")) <= 4;
  }
})) {
  // DO SOMETHING WITH "id" VARIABLE
  ODocument record = id.getRecord();
}
```